# Installing ClamAV on Ubuntu 20.4

Tags: 20.04, clamav

I want to install `clamav`. I follow the [community documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ClamAV) by doing

```
$ sudo apt-get install clamav
```

After confirming with `y`, the following happens at the end of the installation process:

```
Selecting previously unselected package clamav.
Preparing to unpack .../clamav_0.102.4+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking clamav (0.102.4+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up libtfm1:amd64 (0.13-4) ...
Setting up libclamav9:amd64 (0.102.4+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up linux-image-5.4.0-45-generic (5.4.0-45.49) ...
Setting up clamav-base (0.102.4+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
id: ‘clamav’: no such user
Setting up clamav-freshclam (0.102.4+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/clamav-freshclam.service → /lib/systemd/system/clamav-freshclam.service.
Setting up clamav (0.102.4+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.4.0-45-generic (5.4.0-45.49) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-45-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 12: /etc/default/grub: snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.4.0-45-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.4.0-45-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.4.0-45-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What is going on? Is `clamav` not being maintained for Ubuntu 20.4 anymore?

Comment: Have you tried installing ClamTk from the Ubuntu Software Centre?

Comment: @User24601 gives: "Error while installing package: [...], post-installation script return error exit status 1", in line with  what I posted above.

Comment: ok, jhave you seen this resource then? https://kifarunix.com/install-and-use-clamav-on-ubuntu-20-04/

Comment: @N0rbert: I dont have any spaces in my /etc/default/grub. The `grub-mkconfig` appears to complain about the dmic_detect line. I wouldn't know what to do with it, a quick online search suggests that this is necessary for mic/speakers to function.

Answer (score -1):

As one of the comments suggested, it turns out to be an issue with the default way that grub was setup on my system. Run:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

in my case, the following was written there:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0
```

place the `dmic_detect` line inside the `linux_default` line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

save and run

```
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

after that, the installatio nwas without a problem.

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="loglevel=3 snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0"